# Is Riak recommended for storing and streaming large binary files?

Tags: mongodb, riak, clob, nosql

Say, if I store movies, etc., using a Riak database, how do I stream the binaries in chunks to any client (which could be a download-then-play or direct play?) Is Riak recommended for storing large binary files? Also, I've read somewhere that the maximum file is 50 MB or otherwise it will cause problems, but that seems to be old documentation. Could anyone provide more information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We do not recommend storing objects over 50M for performance reasons. Nothing has changed in that regard. Given that, the answer is Riak is not well suited for what you are describing.

We have developed an enterprise product, RiakCS, for a distributed file storage solution (Amazon S3 compatible API) <strike>but this is not an open source project</strike>.

**Edit to add:** We were attempting to incorporate Luwak for large object/file support but unfortunately we are no longer doing so. That project is of course available on github should others want to continue work.

**Updated:** We have now open-sourced Riak CS. See: http://basho.com/riak-cloud-storage/

Comment: What would you recommend from easy of use/administration/maintance perspective: Luwak or RiakCS? I only need fault-tolerant storage for large (gigabytes range) files.

Comment: @Moonwalker - I would highly suggest trying out RiakCS. It's basically designed to do exactly what you're asking, built on top of Riak. Trying to us Luwak inside Riak was our first go at things ... this is better.